# JavaScript throws undefined error when trying to loop through nested JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have am array like this:

```
var jsonObj = {
  "name": "my boards",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "AAA",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "AAA_2",
          "size": 422
        },
        {
          "name": "AAA_2",
          "size": 422
        },
        {
          "name": "AAA_2",
          "size": 422
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "BBB",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "BBB_2",
          "size": 422
        },
        {
          "name": "BBB_2",
          "size": 422
        },
        {
          "name": "BBB_2",
          "size": 422
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "CCC",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "CCC_2",
          "size": 422
        },
        {
          "name": "CCC_2",
          "size": 422
        },
        {
          "name": "CCC_2",
          "size": 422
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to use jquery to fill this object with values inside divs. I think I am getting the dots and brackets wrong. I am trying this:

```
function fill_object() {
  $.each($('.my_div'), function() {
    jsonObj.children["name"] = $(this.id).value();
    jsonObj.children.children["name"] = $(this.id).value();
  });
  return (jsonObj)
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
```

I want to be able to add values to AAA, AAA_2, BBB, BBB_2, CCC and CCC_2

Comment: jsonObj.children is an array...not an object

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: *"I want to be able to add values to AAA, AAA_2, BBB, BBB_2, CCC and CCC_2"* Not sure what that means. Can you provide a simpler example of the input and an example of the expected result?

Comment: is $(this.id).value() going to return an existing key or a new key?

Comment: i'd probably restructure children as an object, not an array, and make the "name" field the key.

Comment: Not sure why you have dup children in nested array but I think this is what you are looking for - https://jsfiddle.net/rutkywc5/

Comment: `.value()` is not a jQuery method.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Alien that is perfect, and exactly what I am looking for. Feel free to create a quick answer for the vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments that this is what you were looking for (was not answering as I was not sure about your requirements)

So the thing is that you need nested loops like

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.children.length; i++) {
    console.log(jsonObj.children[i].name); //outputs name

  for(var j = 0; j < jsonObj.children[i].children.length; j++) {
    console.log(jsonObj.children[i].children[j].name); //outputs nested children names
  }
}
```

Over here, am looping `jsonObj.children` first, and later, I am nesting another `for` loop to iterate over nested array which further has objects with `name` as a key.

You can do a minor optimization here by doing something like

```
for(var i = 0, l = jsonObj.children.length; i < l; i++)
```

So that we only count the `length` of your `array` once. You can do the same for your nested loop.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the optimization tip too.